# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 5 Application to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, .net-4.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying many different things to get my MVC 5 application to work on Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5, but no matter what I do, the website loads with no errors and just loads a blank, white page. 
The server has the latest version of .NET installed,
I've added all the assemblies to the 'bin' folder, I added the dependencies in the Web.Config file, tried using various settings on the IIS application pool, and I even added my MVC application as its own site on IIS.

When I create a test MVC 4 application and publish it, the website works out of the box. It seems like anything that uses .NET 4.0 and below works fine, but any version above that doesn't.

I feel like I've read every single Stack Overflow post, every article on the web and every Microsoft post regarding this issue while getting no results.

**** **UPDATE** ****

I found out that when I type a URL based on the MVC URL/routing conventions (ex. /Home/About) on the MVC 5 app, it gives me an HTTP 404 error, but when I use the same URL on the MVC 4 app, it goes to the correct page.

Comment: Try manually changing the controller/action to see if you can get the routing logic to return.  I would also run fiddler on the client machine to ensure there is no funny business with the authentication.  You want to make sure that your page request is hitting the server and receiving a response.

Comment: @SimonHoulton I tried changing the Index controller action result to just return a string and still nothing. Also, I used Fiddler and I get an HTTP 200 response.

Comment: Are you sure its IIS 6 on Win 2008 R2?

Comment: @PankajKapare Yes, I select Help > About on IIS and it says that the version is IIS 6.1.

Comment: As far as I know you can not install IIS 6.0 on Win 2008 R2. Default version on 2008 R2 is IIS 7.5

Comment: @PankajKapare My mistake, I looked at it again and it's version 6.1 for Microsoft Server, however the IIS version is 7.5. I will change my post to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to use browser' developer tools or Fiddler to check if there is any request being held back or receiving any http errors.

Comment: @PankajKapare I've downloaded Fiddler and I get an HTTP 200 response.

Comment: do you see any content in response? How much is content-length?

Comment: @PankajKapare I get 125 bytes for the header and 0 for the body

Comment: @bkhosh2 can you get it to throw an error, for example if you mispelt the controller.  If not I'm not sure the routing is working and would recommend seeing if URL rewriting is installed on IIS.

Comment: @SimonHoulton I'm not sure routing is the issue because MVC 4 has the same exact routing as MVC 5 and MVC 4 works perfectly fine.

Comment: @SimonHoulton When I type in /Home/About on the MVC 4 app, it goes to the About page; however, when I type the same URL for the MVC 5 app, it gives me a 404 HTTP error.

Comment: Is .NET Framework 4.5 or higher installed on the server? Note that MVC 5 doesn't support .NET 4.0. It seems like you should know that based on your question, but you didn't specifically mention that the server has version 4.5 installed.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes, the server has .NET 4.5 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I ended up doing something similar to OP (I suspect he's solved the issue by now).  I created a test app and that worked out of the box with IIS 7.5 without special handlers or anything.  This is in Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 with everything installed (ASP.NET etc).  The app pool is set to integrated and .NET 4.0.  I did not need to add special handlers.  Once I had a known good application, I went through the web.config of the bad and good ones, and copied code from the good to the bad one.

I believe but am not sure this was the right section. It was present in the bad config but not in the good config.

```
 <handlers>
      <remove name="MvcResourceHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
```